# Entering of char variable in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to make database of students with linked list, but after entering the info about first student I can't enter the name of every other.

```
struct Student
{
    char name[20];
    int egn;
struct Student *next;
}*start=NULL;


void creat()
{
char ch;
do
{
struct Student *newStudent,*current;

newStudent=(struct Student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));

    printf("\nEnter student's name: ");
    gets(newStudent->name);
    printf("Enter student's egn: ");
    scanf("%d",&newStudent->egn);
    newStudent->next=NULL;

if(start==NULL)
{
start=newStudent;
current=newStudent;
}
else
{
current->next=newStudent;
current=newStudent;
}

printf("\nDo you want to creat another : ");
ch=getche();
}while(ch!='n');
}
```

And the result:

```
Enter student's name: First Student
Enter student's egn: 234234
Do you want to creat another : y
Enter student's name: Enter student's egn: 23452342
Do you want to creat another : y
Enter student's name: Enter student's egn: 234234
Do you want to creat another : n
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Probably mixing gets, scanf, and whatever getche is. That getche is probably leaving a \n in the input stream and the gets is picking it up. Also, creat is a system call so it would be a good idea to rename this function.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`, ever. Use `fgets()` here in place of `gets()`, `scanf()`, and `getche()`. For your egn, you'll then have to use `strtol()` to get the number. For the loop condition, read it into an array rather than a single `char`, and test `buffer[0] != 'n'` if `buffer` is the name of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fflush(stdin) before and after gets(newStudent->name); statement